# lov(list of value) in master detail

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and jdeveloper.
I have a table with 3 columns that columns are lov(list of value).
these columns have master and details  relations .
I want to select master column and filtering details columns automaticaly.
can anyone help me ?

Comment: You're not giving a lot to work with here - version of JDev and how you are getting your data - the source- is it ADF BC?
And, not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If Column 1 is a Master column - then what does column 2 - the detail show? Wouldn't you have to select a Cell in Column 1 Master to determine what Column values populate in the Detail column? Hard to visualize what you are trying to do. Provide more detail, pls.

Comment: i have jdeveloper 11g release 2(11.1.2.4.0) .

Comment: I have jdeveloper 11g release 2(11.1.2.4.0) .  column 1 is a master and column 2 is a detail of column 1 and column 3 is detail of column 2. i want when select a value from master ,automatically  filter  column 2 and column 3 .(columns of this table are as lov(list of value)  .